# How do I copy a file with scp with special characters?

Tags: scp

I am trying to copy a file that has colons and periods, e.g., with:

```
scp "test.json-2014-08-07T11:17:58.662378" remote:tmp/

scp test.json-2014-08-07T11\:17\:58.662378 remote:tmp/
```

and combinations with file:

```
scp "file:///home/.../test.json-2014-08-07T11:17:58.662378" remote:tmp/
```

My guess is that scp tries to interprete parts of the file as a server and/or port number. How do I avoid that?

If I rename the file to test.json then `scp test.json remote:tmp/` works ok, but not even `scp test*62378 remote:tmp/`works.

Comment: Let me just note that some obvious "solution" is to rename the file, copy it, and rename it back on the remote server.

Comment: An explanation of why globs (`*`), don't work. It is done in shell, so exactly the same text (argument) will be passed to `scp`. You need to change the text (argument) that is passed to `scp`. (see answer below, for what to change text argument to.)

Comment: It should be noted that `:` is an illegal filename character on OSX, so if you ever need to transfer these files there it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: In cygwin, if the filename starts with a hyphen you can prefix the file with a double hyphen e.g. `scp -- -1.JvSbrpchxuk.png user@example.com:/tmp`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `./` before your filename:

```
scp ./test.json-2014-08-07T11:17:58.662378 remote:tmp/
```

That make `scp` know it's a file. Without it, `scp` thinks it's a hostname because of the colon.

Answer (score 6):

Use the path by prepending `./` and escape your `:`'s. Cyberiti has [more info](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rsync-scp-file-name-with-colon-punctuation-in-it/). Example:

```
scp ./file\:with\:colons.txt remoteserver:
```

Comment: You don't need to escape colon.

Comment: Your escaping of `:` is at shell level, not at scp level.

Comment: Yes, you need to escape. At least in my shell I need the escape.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen: What is your shell? You don't need to escape colon, the shell add backslash for you. You can remove them and see it still works.

Comment: I was wrong. `scp ./test.json-2014-08-07T11:17:58.662378 remote:tmp/` does actually work! Sorry.

Comment: @Gnouc @FinnÅrupNielsen In `bash` some characters including `:` and `@` require escaping when tab completion is used, but if you type the entire command without using tab completion it will work with or without escaping.

Comment: @kasperd: I think it's not required. It's a feature of bash completion. `:` and `@` in string don't have special meaning to shell.

Comment: @Gnouc It is required if you want tab completion to work. If you type the `:` or `@` in a name without escaping and try to complete the rest of the name by pressing tab, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I did not try this version with path prefix:

```
scp /home/.../test.json-2014-08-07T11\:17\:58.662378 remote:tmp/
```

this also works:

```
scp ./test.json-2014-08-07T11\:17\:58.662378 remote:tmp/
```

From https://twitter.com/h0pbeat/status/497319751031353344 and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rsync-scp-file-name-with-colon-punctuation-in-it/ Thanks.

(as the above users managed to answer before me)