# scp refuses to move a file to a local folder

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm trying to move a file from the server to my windows machine using cmd, first try:

```
scp username@lux.technion.ac.il:/home/username/Human_hg19_chr13/Alignment_calls.vcf C:\Users\FF\Desktop\cyberduck
```

The output:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known

lost connection
Connection to lux.technion.ac.il closed.

trying again:

```
scp username@lux.technion.ac.il:/home/username/Human_hg19_chr13/Alignment_calls.vcf C:\Users\FF\Desktop\cyberduck .
```

The output:

Alignment_calls.vcf
100%  964KB  45.9MB/s   00:00

ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known

Which means it almost worked but something went wrong at the end, I'm not sure is it my code?

Comment: it didn't work first time because scp assumes that `C:\Users...` is the host definition - `user@host:/path`. However in the second case you have `.` at the end, so the file most likely was copied to the current directory.

Comment: Related: [How do I copy a file with scp with special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148929/how-do-i-copy-a-file-with-scp-with-special-characters)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what I'm supposed to fix in my code, I'm new at this so sorry for not getting it..

Comment: `scp` uses a remote locatoin as `user@server:/path/to/file` or `server:/path/to/file`. Now if you have a path called `C:\path\to\file`, `scp` will think `C` is a server - it cannot find a server named `C`. Also I am confused: What environment are you using with the target being a windows-style path?

Comment: I'm using cmd, I'm using a windows machine which is where I want to transfer the wanted file.

Answer (score 0):

Meta: although OpenSSH (including `scp`) come from a Unix heritage, this isn't actually a Unix question, it's a Windows question. I approve deleting this if necessary to remove the Q.

1. first go to the desired directory (with `cd/d [drive:]\path`, or `drive:` and/or `cd \path` as needed), then use `.` as the target (as you found)
2. go to the desired *disk* with `drive:` and use `\path` *without* the drive specifier as the target (could also use `cd/d drive:\anywhere` but then #1 is just as easy)
3. `scp` to the current directory with `.` and *then* `move` it to the desired directory
4. use the UNC syntax `\\localhost\c$\path`